# Unable to implement Knox' EnterpiseDeviceManager

Tags: android, sdk, standards, samsung-knox

I am trying to implement the EnterpriseDeviceManager class of the Knox Standard SDK using the given example in the documentation: [Documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gwnn7.png)

However i am getting the following error:[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7asF.png)

My app has the MDM_RESTRICTION permission and I am within a class deriving from Activity.

Is there any known issue?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it has no effect whatsoever and is just an obnoxious error.
I was able to use the class nontheless.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that this is a common error shown when attempting to use this code. If you add the following warning suppression line, then the error underline will go away:

```
@SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
EnterpriseDeviceManager edm = (EnterpriseDeviceManager) getSystemService(EnterpriseDeviceManager.ENTERPRISE_POLICY_SERVICE);
```